# how to count length of list created dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a chat box in which chat messages are fetched in the form of list. My problem is whenever i am clicking on start chat button i have to open chat box and then count the no of list. my chat box is opening but length of list are always zero. how to solve this.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.start_chat', function(){
  var to_user_id = $(this).data('touser_id');
  var to_user_name = $(this).data('tousername');
  //console.log(to_user_id);
  var getdata;
    
  $.ajax({
   url:"chat_id_table.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{to_user_id:to_user_id},
   async:false,
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {    
    //console.log(data);
    getdata = JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log(getdata);
   }
  })
  if($('#user_dialog'+to_user_id).length == 0){
   make_chat_box(to_user_id, to_user_name, getdata);
  }
  var chat_length = $('.msg_list').find("li").length;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the chat data is an async call. so what happens is that the list is counted before the data comes in.
To solve this wrap the list counter in a function and call it after data is in.
fixed code here

```
$(document).on('click', '.start_chat', function(){
        var to_user_id = $(this).data('touser_id');
        var to_user_name = $(this).data('tousername');
        //console.log(to_user_id);
        var getdata;

        $.ajax({
            url:"chat_id_table.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{to_user_id:to_user_id},
            async:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {    
                //console.log(data);
                getdata = JSON.parse(data);
                //console.log(getdata);
                var chat_len = counter();
            }
        })

    });

        function counter(){
          if($('#user_dialog'+to_user_id).length == 0){
            make_chat_box(to_user_id, to_user_name, getdata);
          }
          var chat_length = $('.msg_list').find("li").length;
          return chat_length;
        }
```

Comment: i have implement it but still it shows zero. if i create a function outside on click event then it shows list length but inside on click event it doesn't show its length.can u suggest me how to find list length inside on click event.

Comment: remove asyn:false from ajax